# Store street address & prevent duplicates

Tags: database, web

I have a database that I am accessing through Django & Python. We want to store buildings based on their addresses (not names, since some buildings simply don't have names).

We need to prevent users from entering duplicate entries into our database for the same building. This is made difficult by the way people could type in the addresses (eg. "1000 Main Street" vs. "1000 Main St.")

In what way can we reliably prevent duplicates? I am using a MySQL database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're working only with the U.S., you can use the USPS Address Standardization web service to resolve duplicates:

http://www.usps.com/webtools/address.htm

Answer (score 0):

Address de-duplication is a complicated task. While the USPS web service is alright, it's seriously lacking in some important features. Plus, it's quite inefficient to perform batch de-duplication using a regular web service, performing requests, etc.

And, it appears the USPS has updated their site, so the link Dan posted, while useful, is now broken.

As an updated answer, I'd like to point out that I work for SmartyStreets and we remove duplicates from address lists. You could, for example, upload your list to [CASS-Certified Scrubbing](https://www.smartystreets.com/Products/CASS-Certified-Scrubbing/) and the addresses will be standardized and flagged for duplicates. It's *really* easy this way. If you need point-of-entry validation, take a look at LiveAddress, which provides more important information than the USPS service alone does.